# Entity Framework inline SQL dynamically select table name

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a less than optimal database that I am querying which strangely, instead of storing look up items in a parent child relationship, stores them in individual tables. So, for example, there is a table for countries and one for states etc. 
I cannot change the database structure, keeping this in mind,

I would like to create a method where I simply pass in table name, and a field name, and I get a list of strings that I can use to load a dropdown. (I am using Entity Framework 6.x)

However I am drawing a blank. Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a SQL query string with EF. Just tell it your return type:

```
private List<string> getFieldFromTable(string tableName, string fieldName)
{
    using (var db = new Context())
    {
        var strings = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}",tableName, fieldName)).ToList();
        return strings;
    }

}
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach, since it could lead to a SQL injection attack.