# Entity Framework Select table using a string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to select table with a string when using Entity Framwork generated code?

Example:

```
using (var db = new Model1())
{
    db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = CreateConnectionString();
    var res = from a in db.R1
              select a;
    foreach (var item in res)
    {...}
}
```

But what I want is like

```
using (var db = new Model1())
{
    String tablename = "R1";
    db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = CreateConnectionString();
    var res = from a in db.tablename
              select a;
    foreach (var item in res)
    {...}
}
```

I need to do a select on a number of tables named R1 to R12, they look **almost** the same.

I can solve it with a direct SQL query but I want to use Entity Framework as much as possible.

The post in [Entity Framework inline SQL dynamically select table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749203/entity-framework-inline-sql-dynamically-select-table-name) is almost right, but I want to select all columns and preferbly get right type back.

Or am I going aboutit the wrong way? Should I use something else than EF?

Any help would be preciated!

Comment: you should use a [generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) method, then you can use [db.Set<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). And you have to use reflection to get a type from your string.

Comment: There exists a old (but nice) library for dynamic linq queries. Not sure if it will help you out in this case. You might want to combine it with the stackoverflow question. Links:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032228/how-can-i-dynamically-select-my-table-at-runtime-with-dynamic-linq

Comment: There might be an update to that, or similar, project here, not sure though: https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SqlQuery`:

```
var sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", tablename);
var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<R1>(sql);
```

It could work if all of your tables R1--R2 have the same structure (properties and their types).